Force to recheck location for night light
Introduction:
I've been using night light for many months with no issue. The location would be set using location services; the sunset - sunrise setting would work as it should. Even after connecting to another timezone via VPN the setting would be updated within seconds.
Seemingly after I moved between timezones and changed the timezone setting manually first, before it could be checked automatically, the sunset - sunrise setting got stuck. After coming home, I found that night light kicks in around 14:00, and the usual turn on-off solutions for the related components do not work.
Attempted solutions:

Turning location services on and off
Turning night light on and off
Combinations of the above

Issue:
How to force location to be checked automatically to correct the night light hours as it is meant to work?
Operating system: Ubuntu 22.04
